# SQL - Access 2010 partial duplicates match?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm working on an Access Database for everyday use in a team of 15.
Everyday the team will input 10-15 Names into this database and I need the database to see if the name already exists.

Easy enough, however some names don't match exactly.
For example the team will enter in this format into ONE field:
Lastname, Firstname

But the existing records that are imported from an automated report may have an initial at the end like:
Lastname, Firstname M.

This is enough to make the difference when using this query:

```
SELECT All_test.[Name], All_test.[EjSupervisor], All_test.[ID], All_test.[Department], All_test.[Location], All_test.[EbEmpNumber], All_test.[Date Manager E-mailed]
FROM All_test
WHERE (((All_test.[Name]) In (SELECT [Name] FROM [All_test] As Tmp
GROUP BY [Name],[EjSupervisor]
HAVING Count(*)>1  And [EjSupervisor] = [All_test].[EjSupervisor]))) and len(rtrim(Name) - 3)
```

Completely open to suggestions here.

Comment: You'd need to change your query, but I suggest you consider using `contains` or `LIKE` if you think it's suitable.

Answer (score 1):

*"Everyday the team will input 10-15 Names into this database and I need the database to see if the name already exists."*

For data input, give the users a form with a combo box which presents the existing names.  They can then easily choose from among those names.

When they input a name which does not exist, [Use NotInList Event to Add a Record to Combo Box](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197526).